# EAAccessoryManager notifyObserversThatAccessoryDisconnectedWithUserInfo crashes iOS 11.1.2

Tags: ios, bluetooth

App is crashing while a bluetooth device is disconnected.
I've seen few related threads and they say

"A notification delegate was not reset to nil. A fix has been applied at version 10.3.79."

Following is crash log:

```
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018544c430 objc_msgSend + 16
1   ExternalAccessory               0x000000019c07c4dc -[EAAccessoryManager _notifyObserversThatAccessoryDisconnectedWithUserInfo:] + 104 (EAAccessoryManager.m:909)
2   ExternalAccessory               0x000000019c07eddc -[EAAccessoryManager _externalAccessoryDisconnected:] + 928 (EAAccessoryManager.m:1537)
3   CoreAccessories                 0x00000001a7892ccc __54-[ACCExternalAccessoryProvider ExternalAccessoryLeft:]_block_invoke + 316 (ACCExternalAccessoryProvider.m:453)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000185b6d088 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:994)
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000185b6d048 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:502)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000185b79b74 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1016 (inline_internal.h:2500)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186191eb0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12 (CFRunLoop.c:1815)
8   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018618fa8c __CFRunLoopRun + 2012 (CFRunLoop.c:3111)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001860affb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
10  GraphicsServices                0x0000000187f47f84 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)
11  UIKit                           0x000000018f6842e8 UIApplicationMain + 208 (UIApplication.m:3949)
12  MYAPP                           0x0000000100ab8d58 main + 172 (main.m:16)
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000185bd256c start + 4
```

Comment: Seeing on iOS 11.4.0 on a iPhone 7 user

Comment: I too observing the same behaviour in my App.

Comment: Seeing on iOS 13.1.1 iPhone 8